# SQL - Partition By or Loop to create sub table from master table

Tags: sql, window-functions

I have created a master table running this query :

**Master Table**

```
WITH cfr_pr_audit AS

(WITH cfr_pr AS
(SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS id_seq,
id,
status AS pr_status
FROM infrabi_stg.o_infr_dly_cfr_purchase_request
WHERE snapshot_day = (SELECT max(snapshot_day) FROM infrabi_stg.o_infr_dly_cfr_purchase_request)), 

cfr_pr_audit_pre AS
(SELECT 
purchase_request,
status AS audit_status,
created_by,
created_at
FROM infrabi_stg.o_infr_dly_cfr_purchase_request_audit
WHERE snapshot_day = (SELECT max(snapshot_day) FROM infrabi_stg.o_infr_dly_cfr_purchase_request_audit)
ORDER BY created_at DESC)

SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cfr_pr.id,cfr_pr_audit_pre.audit_status ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS row_seq
FROM cfr_pr LEFT JOIN cfr_pr_audit_pre ON cfr_pr.id = cfr_pr_audit_pre.purchase_request
ORDER BY cfr_pr_audit_pre.created_at DESC)
```

This query returns multiple records for each id - each id has around 9-11 rows with different audit statuses and dates. (below picture is an example of the rows for each id)

[image]

I am trying to create a query that will create a new table, which will have 1 row per id and will combine different details of each id from the master table (in other words pick specific info from the 9-11 rows of each id from master table and create one line per id).

The info I am trying to pull, per id, in the new table is this:

**Info to pull per id**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
(SELECT id FROM cfr_pr_audit WHERE created_at = (SELECT MIN(created_at) FROM cfr_pr_audit WHERE id = '306637') AND id = '306637') AS purchase_request,
(SELECT MIN(created_at) FROM cfr_pr_audit WHERE id = '306637') AS created_at,
(SELECT created_by FROM cfr_pr_audit WHERE created_at = (SELECT MIN(created_at) FROM cfr_pr_audit WHERE id = '306637') AND id = '306637') AS created_by,
(SELECT created_at FROM cfr_pr_audit WHERE created_at = (SELECT created_at FROM cfr_pr_audit WHERE audit_status = 'Status 8' AND row_seq = 1 AND id = '306637') AND NOT pr_status = 'NO PLACED' AND id = '306637') AS submitted_at,
(SELECT created_by FROM cfr_pr_audit WHERE created_at = (SELECT created_at FROM cfr_pr_audit WHERE audit_status = 'Status 8' AND row_seq = 1 AND id = '306637') AND NOT pr_status = 'NO PLACED' AND id = '306637') AS submitted_by,
ISNULL((SELECT created_at FROM cfr_pr_audit WHERE audit_status = 'Status 9' AND row_seq = 1 AND id = '306637'),(SELECT created_at FROM cfr_pr_audit WHERE audit_status = 'Status 10' AND row_seq = 1 AND id = '306637')) AS approved_at,
(SELECT created_at FROM cfr_pr_audit WHERE audit_status = 'Status 11' AND row_seq = 1 AND id = '306637') AS po_created_at
FROM cfr_pr_audit
```

The above query is working for one specific ID (the one I selected - 363114).

How can I make this work for all ids? Something like a loop through the different ids.

I have tried the below options:

***Option 1:***

```
SELECT DISTINCT
id AS purchase_request,
MIN(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS created_at
FROM cfr_pr_audit
```

The partition by is the most logical approach (the one I normally use), however I am stuck in the third value I am trying to get

```
(SELECT created_by FROM cfr_pr_audit WHERE created_at = (SELECT MIN(created_at) FROM cfr_pr_audit WHERE id = '363114') AND id = '363114') AS created_by
```

as I cannot find a way to PARTITION BY here. And the same for the rest of the lines - the MIN(created_at) was the only part I could partition by (second value)

***Option 2:***

I have though of doing something like a loop

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0
SELECT @count = MAX(id_seq) FROM cfr_pr_audit
WHILE @i <= @count
BEGIN 
  SET @i = @i + 1;

  MIN(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY purchase_request) AS created_at
END
```

but not sure if this can work and create one unified table and also if this is even efficient.

Any hint is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation with window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id AS purchase_request,
       MIN(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS created_at,
       FIRST_VALUE(created_by) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY created_at) AS created_by,
       MAX(CASE WHEN audit_status = 'Status 8' AND row_seq = 1 AND pr_status <> 'NO PLACED' THEN created_at END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS submitted_at,
       MAX(CASE WHEN audit_status = 'Status 8' AND row_seq = 1 AND pr_status <> 'NO PLACED' THEN created_by END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS submitted_by,
       ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN audit_status = 'Status 9' AND row_seq = 1 THEN created_at END) OVER (PARTITION BY id),
              MAX(CASE WHEN audit_status = 'Status 10' AND row_seq = 1 THEN created_at END) OVER (PARTITION BY id)) AS approved_at,
       MAX(CASE WHEN audit_status = 'Status 11' AND row_seq = 1 THEN created_at END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS po_created_at
FROM cfr_pr_audit
```